# How/Where do I get the MerchantKeyId and MerchantSecretKey from Cybersource Business centre?

Tags: node.js, cybersource

I am using cybersource-rest-client NPM package to make payments using Cybersource REST API. It all works fine with test values from [cybersource-rest-samples-node](https://github.com/CyberSource/cybersource-rest-samples-node/blob/master/Data/Configuration.js) Configuration files. I have failed to find the corresponding `MerchantKeyId` and `MerchantSecretKey` of my test account to switch from those in the sample config file.

Thanks for your help in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new API Shared Secret. You can follow the steps here: [create shared secret key](https://developer.cybersource.com/api/developer-guides/dita-gettingstarted/authentication/createSharedKey.html). The MerchantKeyId is the "Key" and the MerchantSecretKey is the "Shared Secret Key".